# Page.IsValid is always false on server side validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have used custom validation in my page like

```
    protected void CheckDuplicateCode_Validation(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
        BrokerBL bBL = new BrokerBL(0);
        DataSet bDS = new DataSet();
        bBL.CheckForCode(bDS, txtAgencyCode.Text);
        if (bDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            e.IsValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
```

It is working fine. When I click on Save button Page.IsValid is always false
Please help me !!!

Comment: u mean like      Page.Validate();
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {}

Comment: deleted my comment. Do you really ask us why the code is always executed that sets `e.IsValid = false`? We don't know why that DataTable contains rows.

Comment: that means that if(bDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) is true lol

Comment: When I debug the code, I noticed that the Page.isValid is always false even if  e.IsValid is retured true. This means that Server Validation event is working fine. Only the issue is why Page.IsValid is always false

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the name of ValidationGroup in your CustomValidator and the button is same or not. If not assign common name to them.

Comment: I have checked all the validation group but still does not work